# Why does google scale seem way off?

Tags: google-maps-api, google

I have read similar threads on here regarding the technicality and am in way over my head. I am not a professional cartographer - I am a professional coach driver that uses google maps to plan routes.
What I would like to know is why, when you scale out, countries seem way out of proportion. E.g. The UK and Ireland is the size of half of Europe.

Comment: I dont follow your quesion.  Do you have a screenshot of the error?

Comment: It boils down to 'distortion' towards the poles seen here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercator_projection#Distortion (ignoring the math equations)

Comment: Because they use something called the Mercator projection, which leads to chronic scale distortion the further you get from the equator in both directions. When you go from a 3D world to a 2D representation, you have to sacrifice one of scale, bearing, or shape, essentially. The distances calculated will take this into account, so don't be alarmed. Greenland is not really the size of Africa.

Comment: Ah ok thanks. So does that mean, with the Mercator indices graphic on wikipedia, countries roughly between the tropics are about right ?

Comment: Scale and distance are only really correct on the equator. Beyond that, scale is distorted as the secant of latitude, essentially. Read the [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercator_projection) article, it is good. But, as I say, Google will report correct distances, even if the map looks distorted.

Comment: The Equator is the only line of true scale on the Mercator Projection. Google use the great circle algorithm seen here for DISTANCES https://www.daftlogic.com/projects-google-maps-distance-calculator.htm

Comment: ha hadnt looked at Greenland.